# How do I force browser to automatically retrieve fresh page from server rather than return cached page

Tags: html, spark-java

Have (local) web application, first time user connects to the server via a web browser a popup windows is displayed with a license agreement. If they accept it the popup window is hidden, and an Aysnc call is made to server  that persists the fact that the EULA has been accepted, and the page is recreated so that no popup windows will be displayed (if they reject the EULA the web app exits).

Trouble if the user does nothing else of significance, then later on user connects to the server again via a web browser the browser just returns the cached webpage not the newly created version, so the Eula is shown again.

If they force a refresh then the EULA popup goes away, but that is not easy for user. So how can i force the browser to go to the server to get latest version of page rather than returning the cached page.

This is a html question but maybe useful to know I am using [Spark Framework](http://sparkjava.com/), a Java framework for creating web applications.

Comment: You can try adding a cookie at browser/server end with timed expiry

Comment: @AravindAnil could you expand, how do I do that ?

Comment: Quoting the w3 Schools Create using  `document.cookie = "EULAccepeted=true; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";` and for retrieving `document.cookie will return all cookies in one string much like: EULAccepeted= true` . So based on this value you can decide whether to render fresh from server

Comment: To add on if you are using Cookie/local Storage for this purpose , you may have to get user consent as part of GDPR

Comment: There are many browser refresh plugins are available on play store..

Comment: @AravindAnil i dont get it , where do i put that code intro decide wherther to get again, its just seems like the webrowser just loads the page without going to server ?

Comment: Im now thinking I dont want to introduce cookies, havent need so far. The popup is displayed by an onload event based on a check of eula flag when compiled, if instead I changed the on load javascript to interactively check from server to see if eula flag is set and then if not show the dialog would that work with user having to do hard refresh

Comment: Not an answer because I dont know Spark well enough to be sure, but 
 most servers would have a "request headers" object that could be set. Something like this: ```after((request, response) -> {
    response.header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
});```

Comment: Thanks Graham, I get it now. But I have another solution that seems to work - Added  window.location.reload(true); to the aysnc javascript after page had been recreated/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a solution that works for me. When the user clicks on the OK button it already called a Javascript function that talks to the server, then when it returned it added a message to existing page.

```
function eulaAccept()
    {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('POST', '/start.eulaaccept', true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
       xhr.send("done");
       $('#eula').modal('hide')
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
           {
               alerts=document.getElementById("messages");
               var alert = document.createElement("div");
               var msg   = document.createTextNode("Thankyou for accepting the EULA");
               alert.className = "alert alert-info";
               alert.appendChild(msg);
               alerts.appendChild(alert);
           }
       };
    }
```

But since the server recreates the page I just had to add **window.location.reload(true);** to force a reload the file once the server had returned.

```
function eulaAccept()
    {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('POST', '/start.eulaaccept', true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
       xhr.send("done");
       $('#eula').modal('hide')
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
           {
               window.location.reload(true);
           }
       };
    }
```

(and I removed the message as decided not necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome:
Windows: hold "ctrl" and click on the refresh button
Mac: hold "shift" and click on the refresh button

Firefox:
Windows: hold "ctrl" and press "f5"
Mac: hold "shift" and press "f5"

This is referred to as a "hard refresh".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Konsti219! Great first answer. Don't be afraid to expand it by researching the hard refresh shortcut on other browsers and OSs.

Comment: Thx, but I want it to happen without interaction from user.